# Why is FileMaker's SQL giving me this strange result?

Tags: sql, filemaker

I'm executing the following SQL in with FileMaker's `ExecuteSQL` function:

```
SELECT "location", "account", SUM("amount")
FROM   "TEMP"
GROUP BY "location", "account"
```

It's giving me very strange results.

```
LOC01,Account 1,-5.25
LOC01,Account 2,100811.57
LOC01,Account 3,13298.7299999999999942
LOC01,Account 4,17942.029999999999994
LOC01,Account 5,-12528.279999999999995
LOC01,Account 6,2048.9399999999999995
LOC01,Account 7,547.25
LOC01,Account 8,90295
LOC01,Account 9,-83
LOC01,Account 10,-340.11
LOC01,Account 11,-5619.3499999999999923
LOC01,Account 12,-780
LOC01,Account 13,-450
LOC01,Account 14,-98126.44
LOC01,Account 14
Account 15
Account 15
Account 16
Account 17
Account 17
Account 18,-540
LOC01, Account 14
Account 14
Account 14
Account 17
Account 14
Account 17,0
LOC01,Account 18,-869.95
LOC01,Account 19,-6100.01
LOC01,Account 20,-92849.6899999999999995
LOC01,Account 21,1150
LOC01,Account 22,-7801.4399999999999976
LOC02,Account 1,-4.25
```

Everything looks good until line 15. There we have  the same location and account and no amount, then a few lines with only accounts, some duplicated, most without locations or amounts, some with just the location missing.

This pattern repeats for each location.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is there any data in those records for those missing fields?

Comment: Can you send the data this query is running on?

Comment: Yes, without a list of the actual data in the fields this is impossible to diagnose and assist with.

Comment: Looks like line 15's account number is "Account 14
Account 15
Account 15
Account 16
Account 17
Account 17
Account 18" - suggesting corrupt data or bad data entry.
This pattern repeats (with different values) one more time, then things straighten out at "LOC01,Account 18,-869.95"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because two of your records contain multiple values (separated by carriage returns)  in the `account` field.

Comment: Not sure why I missed such an obvious answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: It's one of those things that become obvious **after** being explained.